# Плавное изменение CSS-свойства при нажатии на ссылку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго здоровья! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать данную задачу средствами jQuery:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если мы нажимаем на ссылку с классом "in", то у DIV-элемента с классом "#st" плавно меняется прозрачность бордера с 0.5 до 1 и потом обратно до 0.5.

Ссылка с классом, на которую мы нажимаем, выглядит так:

```
<a class="in" href="123">добавить</a>
```

Класс DIV-элемента, который должен поменять прозрачность, выглядит так:

```
#st { border: 5px solid rgba(0, 143, 255, 0.5); }
```

Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: '#st' - это id, а не класс

Comment: раз никто не отвечает, посмотрите вот тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030575/possible-to-fade-out-div-border

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать анимацию на `css`, а при клике добавлять класс `clicked`, чтобы она сработала:

```js
$('.in').on('click', function() {
  $('#st').addClass('clicked');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#st').removeClass('clicked');
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
#st {
  border: 5px solid rgba(0, 143, 255, 0.5);
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.clicked {
  animation: fade-bodred 3s linear;
}
@keyframes fade-bodred {
  0% {
    border-color: rgba(0, 143, 255, .5);
  }
  50% {
    border-color: rgba(0, 143, 255, 1);
  }
  100% {
    border-color: rgba(0, 143, 255, .5);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="in" href="#">добавить</a>
<div id="st"></div>
```